# View to fill and center contents in the remaining space Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout which is a view that I need to display under another view, all within a ConstraintLayout. I want to LinearLayout's height to be dynamically equal to the space between the bottom of the above view, and the bottom of the parent. I've tried

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/sample_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
```

without success. I am very new at Android UI work so I'm not sure if I'm using the right layout. Can anyone suggest a better implementation, or a fix to my current attempt?

Comment: You can also post the sample of design that you are trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You means this?:
[image]

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/your_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
    android:background="#0ff"
    android:text="your LinearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/above_view"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>
```

Comment: Yes sir! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can put the `LinearLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout` that is under the needed view, and make the height of the relative layout to fill the space, while you can make the linear layout to be in the center of the relative layout such as:

```
<RelativeLayout ... >
    <LinearLayout 
        ....
        android:centerVertical="true"

</RelativeLayout>
```